# How to send promotion email after quick registration

Tags: 7, emails

In my project there are two types of user.

1. Normal User
2. Lawyer

I create a registration form using profile 2 module. Now problem is I want to send promotion email to **Lawyer** after registration so I create Action for send email and then create trigger for user. In send email I choose `[user:profile-lawyer-registration:user:mail]` for email address. registration has done successfully and receive email about registration link, but not receive the promotion email. They gives following error:

> Error: Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

Status message:

> Success: A welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address.

Comment: Check if your email server is working properly by sending test mail

Comment: I receive a registration link email but not created email

Comment: Also i create rule to send email but registration takes more time and not receive rule email

Comment: Now,Using rules i received email but registration takes 3 min to display success message.This is not good how i can manage them